# How to get a rundeck job PID and echo it

Tags: pid, rundeck

How to get a rundeck jobs PID and then echo it.

Simple task of echo a rundeck jobs PID

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck encapsulates the jobs in Java threads, a good way to track the Rundeck threads is to use [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/), anyway, you can obtain the [Steps](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/terminology.html#job-steps) PIDs in the same UNIX/Linux way. The best approach is to do it on [scripts](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) steps, for example:

```sh
ls &
echo $!
```

Job Definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 0aeaa0f4-d090-4083-b0a5-2878c5f558d1
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        ls &
        echo $!
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0aeaa0f4-d090-4083-b0a5-2878c5f558d1
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlgjG.jpg).

**Update:** same job but using Command step:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 8c59758e-32f3-4166-92b0-50d818074368
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: ls & echo $!
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 8c59758e-32f3-4166-92b0-50d818074368
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3snbo.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

ls &
echo $!

When i tried to execute this commands on Local Command option, result is the an error: 'ls cannot access '&': No such file

Comment: Hi! I edited my answer adding the command step example :-)